# How to crop a shapefile with another shapefile with contour

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, clip, contour

I'm new using QGIS (version 3.22) and I think my doubt is simple, but I didn't find any answer.

I have a vector shapefile from Brazil like this: https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2020/Brasil/BR/BR_UF_2020.zip.

[image]

And I have another shapefile with a contour like one of these: https://dados.ons.org.br/dataset/bacia_contorno.

[image]

I want to use the contour to crop a piece of the shapefile and get the points inside. What I want to do is cut like a "biscuit mold".

[image]

I tried use Vector > Geometry Tool > Clip or Intersection... but the contour is empty inside and result the same contour but not filled inside.

Comment: Sharing your data is great! Even better would be to additionally add a screenshot so people can immediately see what's the case without downloading the data (this is, however, great for testing purpose).

Comment: Ok! I will share!

Comment: I suppose that your contour is a linestring. Convert it into a polygon and try again.

Comment: Thaks! @user30184! Your tip was what I was expecting!

Answer (score 4):

I followed the idea from @user30184 and found how to convert line to polygon and it solved my problem.

I only click in Vector > Geometry Tools > Lines to Polygons and selected the layer with contour.